# SQL intersect get all matching rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables with the same structure.

```
FIELD 1      INT
FIELD 2      VARCHAR(32)
```

The query has to get Distinct FIELD 1 for all records from TABLE 2 where a match the same count and values for FIELD 2 without regard to the value of FIELD 1 - only the grouped by count of FIELD 1 has to match.

Example data:

**TABLE 1**

```
1     A
1     B
2     C
2     D
2     E
3     G
3     H
```

**TABLE 2**

```
8     A
8     B
9     E
9     D
9     C
10    F
11    G
11    H
```

The results of the query should be

```
8
9
11
```

I have tried various combinations of Intersect and Group By but I cannot get this just right.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
with cte as
(select t2.*,
        count(t1.field1) over (partition by t1.field2) t1c,
        count(t2.field1) over (partition by t2.field2) t2c
 from table1 t1
 full join table2 t2 on t1.field2 = t2.field2)
select distinct field1 from cte where t1c=t2c
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a2e6/2).

Comment: This works perfectly, and thanks for the SQLFiddle to boot. What a cool way to share this kind of problem solving.  You are a scholar my friend.

Comment: +1 . . . A much more concise answer than mine -- I'll have to remember it. (I think I've been doing these queries since before window functions were invented.)

Answer (score 0):

The logic here in SQL is a bit complicated.  Here is the idea (which is simpler than the SQL).  First count the number of elements for each `f1` in each table.  You only need to keep pairs where these are equal.

Then count the number that are in common for each pair of `f1`.  The pairs match when this count matches the total count for the columns.

Here is SQL that does this:

```
with t1 as (
       select 1 as f1, 'A' as f2 union all
       select 1, 'B' union all
       select 2, 'C' union all
       select 2, 'D' union all
       select 2, 'E' union all
       select 3, 'G' union all
       select 3, 'H'
     ),
     t2 as (
       select 8 as f1, 'A' as f2 union all
       select 8, 'B' union all
       select 9, 'E' union all
       select 9, 'D' union all
       select 9, 'C' union all
       select 10, 'F' union all
       select 11, 'G' union all
       select 11, 'H'
    )
select driver.f11, driver.f12
from ((select t1.f1 as f11, f2cnt1, t2.f1 as f12, f2cnt2
       from (select t1.f1, count(*) as f2cnt1
             from t1
             group by t1.f1
            ) t1 join
            (select t2.f1, count(*) as f2cnt2
             from t2
             group by t2.f1
            ) t2
            on t1.f2cnt1 = t2.f2cnt2
      )
     ) driver join
     (select t1.f1 as f11, t2.f1 as f12, count(*) as InCommon
      from t1 join
           t2
           on t1.f2 = t2.f2
      group by t1.f1, t2.f1
     ) common
     on driver.f11 = common.f11 and
        driver.f12 = common.f12
where driver.f2cnt1 = common.InCommon;
```

The SQLFiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4687).

Comment: Thank you, this is similar to my failed attempt but yours actually works and you did it with a single statement.